# Ubuntu 22.04 and epsonscan2: scanner detected, but I still can't scan

Tags: scanner, udev, ubuntu-22.04, sane

Epson DS-6500. USB scanner (not networked). Works on Widows 10, not on Ubuntu 22.04.

I've installed `epsonscan2` by downloading from [here](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) and extracting to directory "epson' that has the proper permissions.  (Otherwise I get an error, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/908825).)

```
$ sudo chown -Rv _apt:root epson/
$ sudo chmod -Rv 700 epson/
$ sudo su
$ cd epson
$ apt install ./epsonscan2_6.7.61.0-1_amd64.deb
$ shudown -r now
```

Using the simple-scan gui, it finds the scanner, but when I try to scan, it runs for a while and then pops up, "Failed to scan.  Unable to connect to scanner."

```
$ epsonscan2 -l
 === List of available devices ==
device ID :DS-5500/DS-6500/DS-7500:001:012
ModelID:ES00CC

$ epsonscan2 -gs
ERROR : An unexpected error occurred. Epson Scan 2 will close.
```

I notice that the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules` is quite short and does not include my scanner.  Examples of that same file that I see on [German](https://forum-ubuntuusers-de.translate.goog/topic/scanner-epson-perfection-1250/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US) and [Italian](https://forum-ubuntu--it-org.translate.goog/viewtopic.php?t=630885&start=40&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US) fora from 2017-18 are much longer and do include it:

```
# Epson DS-5500 | Epson DS-6500 | Epson DS-7500
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0145", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

On the other hand, `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-epsonscan2.rules` does include it:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="epsonscan2_esci_rules_end"
ENV{DEVTYPE}!="usb_device", GOTO="epsonscan2_esci_rules_end"
ATTR{idVendor}!="04b8", GOTO="epsonscan2_esci_rules_end"
...
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0145", ENV{epsonscan2_driver}="esci"
```

I'm not clear if this is sufficient?

```
$ lsusb | grep -i epson
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04b8:0145 Seiko Epson Corp. Epson DS-6500

$ sane-find-scanner
[snip]
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0145 [Epson DS-6500]) at libusb:001:012 
[snip]
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
[snip]

$ scanimage -L
[04:26:20.458732] [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Address already in use
device `epsonscan2:DS-5500/DS-6500/DS-7500:001:012:esci2:usb:ES00CC:325' is a EPSON DS-5500/DS-6500/DS-7500:001:012 flatbed scanner

$ export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255 && scanimage -L

[05:07:44.037391] [sanei_debug] Setting debug level of dll to 255.
[05:07:44.037456] [dll] sane_init: SANE dll backend version 1.0.13 from sane-backends 1.1.1-debian
[05:07:44.037468] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `./dll.d'
[05:07:44.037486] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: attempting to open directory `/etc/sane.d/dll.d'
[05:07:44.037505] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: using config directory `/etc/sane.d/dll.d'
[05:07:44.037526] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: considering /etc/sane.d/dll.d/hplip
[05:07:44.037551] [dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.d/hplip
[05:07:44.037575] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `hpaio'
[05:07:44.037589] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: considering /etc/sane.d/dll.d/airscan
[05:07:44.037607] [dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.d/airscan
[05:07:44.037618] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `airscan'
[05:07:44.037629] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: considering /etc/sane.d/dll.d/epsonscan2
[05:07:44.037646] [dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.d/epsonscan2
[05:07:44.037657] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `epsonscan2'
[05:07:44.037674] [dll] sane_init/read_dlld: done.
[05:07:44.037690] [dll] sane_init/read_config: reading dll.conf
[05:07:44.037706] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `net'
[snip...]

[05:07:44.038375] [dll] add_backend: adding backend `xerox_mfp'
[05:07:44.038400] [dll] sane_get_devices

[05:07:44.038411] [dll] load: searching backend `xerox_mfp' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.038419] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1'
[05:07:44.038436] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1'
[05:07:44.038578] [dll] init: initializing backend `xerox_mfp'
[05:07:44.044901] [dll] init: backend `xerox_mfp' is version 1.0.13
[05:07:44.045001] [dll] load: searching backend `v4l' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.045012] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[05:07:44.045025] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.045032] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[05:07:44.045043] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.045050] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[05:07:44.045060] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.045067] [dll] load: couldn't find backend `v4l' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.045075] [dll] load: searching backend `umax1220u' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.045083] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax1220u.so.1'
[05:07:44.045095] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax1220u.so.1'
[05:07:44.045227] [dll] init: initializing backend `umax1220u'
[05:07:44.051234] [dll] init: backend `umax1220u' is version 1.0.2
[05:07:44.051249] [dll] load: searching backend `umax' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.051256] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax.so.1'
[05:07:44.051270] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-umax.so.1'
[05:07:44.051452] [dll] init: initializing backend `umax'
[05:07:44.059791] [dll] init: backend `umax' is version 1.0.45
[snip ...]

[05:07:44.101844] [dll] load: searching backend `pixma' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.101851] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1'
[05:07:44.101877] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pixma.so.1'
[05:07:44.102031] [dll] init: initializing backend `pixma'
[05:07:44.106405] [dll] init: backend `pixma' is version 1.0.28
[05:07:44.106688] [bjnp] create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed - Address already in use
[05:07:44.627860] [dll] load: searching backend `pint' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:44.627895] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pint.so.1'
[05:07:44.627916] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-pint.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.627924] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-pint.so.1'
[05:07:44.627936] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-pint.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.627944] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-pint.so.1'
[05:07:44.627955] [dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-pint.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[05:07:44.627965] [dll] load: couldn't find backend `pint' (No such file or directory)
[snip ...]

[05:07:54.156559] [dll] load: searching backend `epsonscan2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:54.156571] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epsonscan2.so.1'
[05:07:54.156603] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-epsonscan2.so.1'
[05:07:54.157471] [dll] init: initializing backend `epsonscan2'
[05:07:54.157498] [dll] init: backend `epsonscan2' is version 1.1.0
[snip ...]

[05:07:56.367278] [dll] load: searching backend `hpaio' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
[05:07:56.367321] [dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpaio.so.1'
[05:07:56.367348] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpaio.so.1'
[05:07:56.368442] [dll] init: initializing backend `hpaio'
[05:07:56.369278] [dll] init: backend `hpaio' is version 1.0.0
[05:07:56.387221] [dll] sane_get_devices: found 1 devices
[05:07:56.387249] [dll] sane_exit: exiting
[05:07:56.387259] [dll] sane_exit: calling backend `xerox_mfp's exit function
[snip ...]

[05:07:56.392356] [dll] sane_exit: calling backend `epsonscan2's exit function
[05:07:56.392375] [dll] sane_exit: calling backend `airscan's exit function
[05:07:56.393641] [dll] sane_exit: calling backend `hpaio's exit function
[05:07:56.394282] [dll] sane_exit: finished
device `epsonscan2:DS-5500/DS-6500/DS-7500:001:012:esci2:usb:ES00CC:325' is a EPSON DS-5500/DS-6500/DS-7500:001:012 flatbed scanner
```